# Use Network Services for FDT

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop, fdt

I've recently started using FDT, for a while I was using FlashDevelop, it had a really handy feature in Compiler options where you can set UseNetworkServices to false which would stop the compiled swf from connecting to the internet and became very useful for running standalone flash apps without security warnings when loading in an external xml file etc.

Does anybody know if FDT has a similar function? If there isn't a way, then no worries, I can compile the project in Flash Develop, however it would be best if I can do it from FDT.

Cheers guys,
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open run configurations for your project and add -`use-network=true` to the compiler arguments.